# Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded py2App

Tags: python, py2exe, py2app

I've searched google pretty thoroughly, but can't find an answer to this. When I try to build with py2app I get this error: 
  Would it possibly be caused by using a module such as 'gspread' in the code? Or because I'm using wxpython? The troubling thing is that 'python setup.py py2app -A' runs without issue.

```
running py2app
creating /Users/Bailejor/Desktop/build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app
creating /Users/Bailejor/Desktop/build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/Bailejor/Desktop/build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/temp
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/python2.7-standalone/app/Frameworks
*** using recipe: virtualenv ***
*** using recipe: ftplib ***
*** using recipe: lxml ***
*** using recipe: PIL ***
*** using recipe: xml ***
*** using recipe: sip ***
*** using recipe: matplotlib ***
*** using recipe: pydoc ***
*** using recipe: docutils ***
*** using recipe: scipy ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app-0.9-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 659, in run
    self._run()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app-0.9-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 865, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app-0.9-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 943, in run_normal
    self.process_recipes(mf, filters, flatpackages, loader_files)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app-0.9-py2.7.egg/py2app/build_app.py", line 833, in process_recipes
    find_needed_modules(mf, packages=rval['packages'])
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/find_modules.py", line 289, in find_needed_modules
    m = mf.import_hook(package, None, ["*"])
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 927, in import_hook
    for s in self._ensure_fromlist(m, fromlist):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1053, in _ensure_fromlist
    submod = self._import_module(sub, fullname, m)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1260, in _scan_ast
    visitor.visit(co)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 241, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 249, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 241, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 615, in visit_ImportFrom
    self._process_import(node.module or '', _ast_names(node.names), level)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1029, in _load_tail
    result = self._import_module(head, mname, result)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1105, in _import_module
    m = self._load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1178, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(co, m)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1251, in _scan_code
    self._scan_ast(co, m)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1260, in _scan_ast
    visitor.visit(co)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 241, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 249, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 241, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 251, in generic_visit
    self.visit(value)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 241, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 245, in generic_visit
    for field, value in iter_fields(node):
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Here is my code as suggested (Thanks for the suggestion):

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import itertools
from itertools import chain
import getpass
import gspread
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import sys

####################################################################################################
class TopPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""
    #Top PANEL
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        grid = gridlib.Grid(self)
        grid.CreateGrid(25,12)
        grid.SetColLabelValue(0, "Index")
        self.buttonPlus = wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "+", size=(50, 28))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


########################################################################################################
class BottomPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""
    #Bottom PANEL
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        #Sizers------------------------------------------------------------
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer2=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer3=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer4=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(1,2))
        self.axe = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.figurecanvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.barseries = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(140, -1))
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self, label="Enter Series to Bar:")
        self.buttonUpdate = wx.Button(self, label="Update Figure")
        self.buttonPlot = wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Plot", size=(60,28))
        self.buttonClear = wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Clear", size=(60,28))
        self.buttonSave=wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Save", size=(60, 28))
        self.buttonNext=wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Next", size=(60, 28))
        self.buttonPrev=wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Last", size=(60, 28))
        self.buttonGplot=wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Gplot", size=(60, 28))
        sampleList = ['Yes', 'No']
        self.rb = wx.RadioBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Secondary Vertical Axis", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, sampleList, 2, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS)
        #Button Binders------------------------------------------------------
        self.buttonSave.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.saveFig)
        self.buttonPlot.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.plotFig)
        self.buttonClear.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clearFig)
        self.buttonGplot.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.googlefunc)
        self.buttonNext.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.nextButtonFunc)
        self.buttonPrev.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.prevButtonFunc)
        #--------------------------------------------------------------------
        #Add to Sizers-------------------------------------------------------
        self.sizer.Add(self.figurecanvas, proportion=2, border=1, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer2.Add(self.rb, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.sizer2.Add(self.lblname, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.sizer2.Add(self.barseries, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.sizer2.Add(self.buttonUpdate, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)

        self.sizer3.Add(self.buttonGplot, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.sizer3.Add(self.buttonPrev, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.sizer3.Add(self.buttonPlot, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.sizer4.Add(self.buttonSave, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.sizer4.Add(self.buttonNext, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.sizer4.Add(self.buttonClear, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)

        self.sizer.Add(self.sizer2, 0, wx.TOP)
        self.sizer.Add(self.sizer3, 0)
        self.sizer.Add(self.sizer4, 0)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.sheetcounter=[]

#Begin Google Sheets Function-------------------------------------------------------------
    def googlefunc(self, e):
        usernam = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Enter Novel Responses Username")
        if usernam.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
            usernm=usernam.GetValue()
            usernam.Destroy()
        else:
            usernam.Destroy()
        convert=usernm + "@gmail.com"

        dlg1 = wx.PasswordEntryDialog(parent=None,message="Please enter your password")
        if dlg1.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
            pw=dlg1.GetValue()
            dlg1.Destroy

        gc = gspread.login(convert, pw)
        dlg2 = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Which client would you like to view progress of?")
        if dlg2.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
            self.client=dlg2.GetValue()
            dlg2.Destroy()

        wks = gc.open(self.client)

        for i, worksheet in enumerate(wks.worksheets()):
            filename = self.client + '-worksheet' + str(i) + '.csv'
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerows(worksheet.get_all_values())
            self.sheetcount = i + 1
        print "There are "+str(self.sheetcount)+" client goals that have been charted."
        self.gplot(jor=0, currentsheet=0)

    def gplot(self, jor, currentsheet):
        lst = ["Bar Series", "Multiple Vertical Axes"]
        if  jor < (self.sheetcount):
            df = pd.read_csv((self.client+'-worksheet'+str(currentsheet)+'.csv'), index_col=0, header=0, sep=',')
            phasechange = df['Phase Change'].dropna()
            phaselabel=df['Phase Label'].values
            phaselabel1=phaselabel
            print phaselabel1
            get_title=str(df['Title'].iloc[0])
            get_y=str(df['Y-Axis Title'].iloc[0])
            get_x=df.index.name
            df=df.dropna(axis=1)
            markers=itertools.cycle(('o', 's', 'D', 's', 'h', '8'))
            markercolor=itertools.cycle(('k', 'w'))
            max_value=(df.values.max()) * 1.5
            print max_value
            fig=plt.figure(1)
            ax=self.axe
            ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
            ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
            ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
            ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
            ax.set_ylabel(get_y)
            ax.axes.set_ylim([0, max_value])
            fig.set_tight_layout(True)
            for col in (df):
                df[col].plot(x=get_x, grid=False, marker=markers.next(), markerfacecolor=markercolor.next(), title=get_title, color='k', ax=ax)
                for phase in phasechange:
                    ax.axvline(x=phase, ymin=0, ymax=1.0, linewidth=12, color='w')
                    ax.axvline(x=phase, ymin=0, ymax=1.0, linewidth=1, color='k')
            phasechange = phasechange + 1
            self.figurecanvas.draw()




        #dlg3 = wx.MultiChoiceDialog( self, "Choose Specific Options for your plot", "Plot Options", lst)
        #if (dlg3.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK):
            #selections = dlg3.GetSelections()
            #strings = [lst[x] for x in selections]
            #if "Bar Series" and "Multiple Vertical Axes" in strings:
                #print "You selected Bar series and multi vert axis"
                #dlg4 = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Which series would you like to bar?")
                #if dlg4.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
                    #get_bar=dlg2.GetValue()
                    #dlg4.Destroy()
                #use Recursion here call gplot again"
                #dlg3.Destroy()
            #elif "Bar Series" in strings:
            #print "You selected Bar Series"
        #else:
            #dlg3.Destroy()

        return (jor, currentsheet)

                #self.deletecsv(sheetcount, currentsheet, client)

    #def deletecsv(self, sheetcount, currentsheet, client):
    #currentsheet=0
    #for _ in xrange(sheetcount):
    #os.remove(client+'-worksheet'+str(currentsheet)+'.csv')
    #currentsheet=currentsheet + 1
#--END Gplot Function-------------------------------------------------------------------------


#--Next Button Function-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def nextButtonFunc(self, event):
        if len(self.sheetcounter) < (self.sheetcount):
            self.sheetcounter.append('l')
            i2=len(self.sheetcounter)
            jor, currentsheet = self.gplot(jor=i2, currentsheet=i2)
            self.axe.clear()
            print jor, currentsheet
            self.gplot(jor, currentsheet)

#--Prev Button Function-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def prevButtonFunc(self, event):
        if 0< len(self.sheetcounter) <= (self.sheetcount):
            del self.sheetcounter[-1]
            i2=len(self.sheetcounter)
            jor, currentsheet = self.gplot(jor=i2, currentsheet=i2)
            self.axe.clear()
            print jor, currentsheet
            self.gplot(jor, currentsheet)
#--Save Figure Function--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def saveFig(self, event):
        filename=wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Please enter a name to save figure", "Save")
        if filename.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
            filename=filename.GetValue()
            self.figure.savefig(filename+".png")
#--Plot Figure Function--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def plotFig(self, event):

        self.axe.plot(range(10), color='green')
        self.figurecanvas.draw()
#--Clear Figure Function------------------------------------------------------------------
    def clearFig(self, event):
        del self.sheetcounter[:]
        self.figure.set_canvas(self.figurecanvas)
        self.axe.clear()
        self.figurecanvas.draw()
        self.SetSize((self.Size[0],self.figurecanvas.Size[1]))
        currentsheet=0
        for _ in xrange(self.sheetcount):
            os.remove(self.client+'-worksheet'+str(currentsheet)+'.csv')
            currentsheet=currentsheet +1
#########################################################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    #MAIN FRAME
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="SSD-Single Subject Designs", size=(1100, 650))

        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        topP = TopPanel(splitter)
        bottomP = BottomPanel(splitter)
#----Start Menubar-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        first=wx.Menu()
        second=wx.Menu()
        third=wx.Menu()
        fourth=wx.Menu()

        first.Append(wx.NewId(),"New Window", "This is a new window")
        first.Append(wx.NewId(),"Open...", "This will open a new window")
        first.Append(wx.NewId(), "Save Dataframe", "")
        first.Append(wx.NewId(), "Save As", "")
        first.AppendSeparator()
        quitter=first.Append(wx.NewId(),"Exit", "This will close the program")

        second.Append(wx.NewId(), "Cut", "This will cut the selection")
        second.Append(wx.NewId(), "Copy", "This will copy the selection")
        second.Append(wx.NewId(), "Paste", "This will paste the selection")

        mbl=wx.Menu()
        mbl.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Two Baselines")
        mbl.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Three Baselines")
        mbl.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Four Baselines")
        mbl.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Five Baselines")
        mbl.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Six Baselines")

        third.Append(wx.NewId(), "Analyze IOA", "Analyze Interobserver Agreement Data")

        third.Append(wx.NewId(), "AB.. Design", "A simple baseline, intervention design with x phases.")
        third.AppendMenu(wx.ID_ANY, "Multiple Baseline Design", mbl)
        third.Append(wx.NewId(), "Changing Criterion Design", "A design with several subphases within the treatment phase.")
        third.Append(wx.NewId(), "Multiple-Treatment Design", "A design with 2 or more treatments in an intervention phase.")
        googler=fourth.Append(wx.NewId(), "Import from Google Sheets", "Import a data set from Google")
        fourth.Append(wx.NewId(), "Import from Excel", "Import a data set from Microsoft Excel")
        menubar.Append(first, "File")
        menubar.Append(second, "Edit")
        menubar.Append(third, "Analyze")
        menubar.Append(fourth, "Import")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Quit, quitter)
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.googlefunc, googler)
#--ENDMENUBAR-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # split the window
        splitter.SplitHorizontally(topP, bottomP)
        splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(200)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
#--QUIT FUNCTION-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def Quit(self, e):
        yesNoBox=wx.MessageDialog(None, "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Exit?", wx.YES_NO)
        yesNoAnswer=yesNoBox.ShowModal()
        print yesNoAnswer
        if yesNoAnswer == 5103:
            self.Close()
            yesNoBox.Destroy()
        else:
            yesNoBox.Destroy()
#End of Quit Function---------------------------------------------------------------------
########################################################################################################
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The traceback shouldn't start with modulegraph, but pointing to a line on your module, right? Perhaps you have missed to paste the initial lines from the traceback?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I thought it was just repeating itself so I shortened it. Updated now!

Comment: Still had to shorten it quite a bit. Was 300k characters w/ 30k limit, but I captured the start of it at least.

Comment: So, I don't have an answer (sorry), but I was reading [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727621/py2app-throws-errno-35-resource-not-available-during-unconditional-imports) and apparently py2app can have recursion problems for other modules like scipy, and these can be avoided by increasing the recursion limit with i.e. `sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)` (default is 1000). I can't say if it'll work, but would you like to try?

Comment: Also, perhaps [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/bugs/32/) might interest you? I see you're using `wx`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I already tried the recursion limit trick to no avail. I'm not sure how to carry out the second. I see several path.py files on my computer.

Comment: pandas module also causes this recursion error. Remove it and check.

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter this problem, and i have tried many many ways and solution to solve it. Finally i find that it seems the problem is resulted by modulegraph module. Then i search https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/ and at the end of this page, it indicates that Requires Distributions modulegraph (>=0.15) macholib (>=1.8) altgraph (>=0.13)so all you need to do is to download the latest package file of modulegraph, macholib, and altgraph, download the whl file, and use pip install XXX.whl.after doing this, download the whl file of py2app latest version, and also usepip install XXX.whl to install py2app.finally you can pack your python into app file.just make sure all the module needs to be the newest.hope this can help you.